# Don't validate nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't want to validate & save nested attributes for the model while saving parent model.

```
class Car
  has_many :models
  nested_attributes_for :models
end

class Model
  belongs_to :car
end

car = Car.create(name: "Tata")
car.model_attributes({name: "Nano"},{name: "Vista"})
car.save!
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: This should help `has_many :models, :inverse_of => :car`

Comment: Just do not set the nested attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `:autosave` to false, this will prevent saving nested attributes

```
class Car
  has_many :models, autosave: false
end
```